# Popen and python command

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

i have

```
p1=subprocess.Popen([python %s.py args.server],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

python "script.py"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. i think that's a problem of executing python commands in popen ,windows ; what should i do in this case

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the Python executable's directory is present in the `PATH` environment variable and that the directory of your `script.py` file is present in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: Post the exact code you are running and the exact message you receive. The message you posted indicates that Windows cannot find the program you are trying to execute.

Comment: python ../../script/script.py -H localhost xenosmilus2
'"python xenosmilus2.py"' isn't recognized as a internal or external command.
  File "../../script/script.py", line 241, in <module>
    _cnf = json.loads(p1.stdout.read())
  File "C:\python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
  raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: It's not clear to me at this point whether you have problems launching Python or in the Python code you launch.